# R package copula: does dimension order matter in cCopula?

Tags: r

I'm trying to to get a sample conditional on a value in one dimension using `cCopula` from R's `copula` package.  I get the expected behavior when the conditioned value is in the first dimension, but not in other dimensions.

The first dimension works as expected:

```
cc <- claytonCopula(.5, dim = 2)
U <- cCopula(cbind(.1, runif(1000)), copula = cc, inverse = TRUE)
> head(U)
     [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.1 0.02399811
[2,]  0.1 0.51941744
[3,]  0.1 0.54457839
[4,]  0.1 0.30212338
[5,]  0.1 0.16368668
[6,]  0.1 0.43865921
```

The second does not.  I expect .1 to be the value in the second column.

```
U <- cCopula(cbind(runif(1000), .1), copula = cc, inverse = TRUE)
head(U)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.85596900 0.19792006
[2,] 0.05069967 0.02663780
[3,] 0.87673450 0.20056410
[4,] 0.52156481 0.14809874
[5,] 0.42508008 0.13026719
[6,] 0.04852083 0.02567477
```

My question is: should the order matter in `cCopula`?  If yes, how can I work around it, and if no, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The order does matter in `cCopula`. Check the `Value` section in the documentation for that function. Each column "contains the conditional copula function values", conditioned on the columns before it.

Not sure why you'd expect to have a column of `0.1` in your second example; even in the first example, that second column is not the random uniform values:

```
set.seed(1)
cc <- claytonCopula(.5, dim = 2)
Z <- cbind(.1, runif(1000))
U <- cCopula(Z, copula = cc, inverse = TRUE)

> head(Z)
     [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.1 0.2655087
[2,]  0.1 0.3721239
[3,]  0.1 0.5728534
[4,]  0.1 0.9082078
[5,]  0.1 0.2016819
[6,]  0.1 0.8983897
> head(U)
     [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.1 0.2293643
[2,]  0.1 0.3274950
[3,]  0.1 0.5232455
[4,]  0.1 0.8893238
[5,]  0.1 0.1723588
[6,]  0.1 0.8777835
```

Comment: Thanks--I suspected that was the case.  My follow-up from the above question is: how can I condition on a value in another component?  I can't tell from the documentation how I can fix the value of dimension 2 and sample conditional values for other dimensions, for example.

Comment: Do you mean you want to compute `C(X_i|X_2)` where `i != 2` are the other dimensions (conditioning only on X_2 and nothing else)? It might not be computationally efficient, but you could do `cCopula(Z[,c(2,i)], ...)[,2]` and loop over `i`. This will condition on dimension 2 only.

Comment: More generally, I want to sample from `C(X_{-i} | X_i)`.  Your idea swaps the input columns to `cCopula`, but I don't think that would work if the copula is asymmetric: I'd still be conditioning on the first dimension.  If `cCopula` always conditions on the first dimensions by default, then maybe I need a way to reorder the dimensions of the copula instead.

Comment: Hmm, you might have some luck by repeatedly applying Bayes theorem to get the conditionals you want. I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with copulas to know about the implications of just swapping the input columns. My guess is it doesn't matter, even if the copula is asymmetric, since the marginals are the same and you're inputting uniforms (maybe that was just part of your example though). Could you just have `C(X_{-i} | X_i) = C(X_1,...,X_d) / C(X_i)`?